# Java; Splitting a string into segments

Tags: java, regex, string

(Warning - made with Google Translate)

I am learning to use regular expressions while creating a simple program for myself that would take as input a string consisting of formulas for various dice rolls and modifiers to them. Example:

`2d6+13+3d10-1d4+5+1d8-6`

I have a regular expression to search for segments like "+-XdY":

`(^|[\\+-])[1-9]\\d*d[1-9]\\d*`

I want to cut such segments from a string, store them as an array for further processing, and at the same time remove them from the string

`Input - string "2d6+13+3d10-1d4+5+1d8-6"`

`Output - string "+13+5-6" (without any +-XdY) and array of strings {"2d6", "+3d10", "-1d4", "+1d8"} (all of +-XdY)`

so after that it can be repeated with modifiers (using another regex)

`Input - string "+13+5-6"`

`Output - string "" and array of strings {"+13", "+5", "-6"}`

and, by the remaining string at the end, understand whether the data was entered correctly or not (empty = good).

The problem is that I simply cannot find a suitable tool to cut certain fragments from the string and save them as an array.

Can you help me? Or perhaps there is a simpler algorithm for this task?

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Please rephrase your question and show us what the expected output should be here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split before `+` or `-`:

```
String[] parts = str.split("(?=[+-])");
```

---

Test code:

```java
String str = "2d6+13+3d10-1d4+5+1d8-6";
String[] parts = str.split("(?=[+-])");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parts));
```

Output:

```
[2d6, +13, +3d10, -1d4, +5, +1d8, -6]
```